# Sending an image with text overlay in email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails with images embedded in the email.

I'm just wondering what the best way to achieve the following usecase is:

Sending an image (like a picture of a gift card) with text overlaying it. Some of the text is standard on each email, other text is variable (like Gift Card code, and amount of gift card).

For styling, I'm obviously using tables and colspans, and all that fun stuff we are forced to use for HTML emails, but since I want the image to be a certain width (approximately 400px, or a bit more than half the width of a standard email window) and I also want the text to fit on the image, I'm wondering what the best way to ensure that the text doesn't escape the boundary of the image is.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a new image with the text on it using GD or imagemagik

Comment: Your best bet is to generate the image on the server using some library such as imagemagick, including the text and labelling, then send out the entire thing as an inline attachment in your email.

Comment: i personally would put all the text in plane sections of the email with the graphics around it, so that you don't have to create a separate image for each email

Comment: Is there a reason that generating a new image is better than using text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using tables, set your image as the background for a table cell and put the text inside the cell.   You can keep the text inside your arbitrary picture border by setting the padding of the cell.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Just as a side point, I notice that GMail colors some of the text purple in subsequent messages (as it's the same content as previous messages, it tries to hide it). Do you know of any ways to prevent this?

Comment: Nope sorry.  The ways of Gmail, they are clouded in enigma and wrapped in algorithm.

Comment: :) I found some suggestions but nothing's worked yet. Thanks anyway